# Boundary condition of vibrating flange in ANSYS mechanical

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, vibration, ansys

I have a structure with both sides a having flange. The vibration comes to plant from one of the flanges. The structure has it's own fixed support on its bottom, bearing its weight.

I assumed force is applied to the front face of one flange by setting its face as force excitation. and two pad on bot of structure as fixed support.

I know both sides of the structure have constraints but don't know what constraint, it's not fixed, not simply supp not compressible only, is what? maybe elastic? How to calculate it's stiffness?